# awk adding up two rows if the rows have a matching name

Tags: command-line, bash, awk, csv

I am trying to take a csv file that looks like

```
customerID,firstname,lastname,charge
5efc522,Romo,goodrick,37.89
4a7f057,jeny,vel,38.39
5efc522,Romo,goodrick,39.00
```

and make it into

```
firstname,lastname,chargetotal,customerID
ROMO,goodrick,76.89,5efc522
jeny,vel,38.39,4a7f057
```

so far I know that I can do

```
awk '{arr[$1]+=$4;}
END{
FOR (i in arr) {
print i, arr[i];}
'< file
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: If your input is CSV, then you'll need to set the field separator `FS` to `,` - if you want CSV output you'll want to do the same for `OFS`. Since this appears to be an assignment, see if you can get a bit further once you have done that.

Comment: ya it's one part of the assignment and yes i should have put it BEGIN{FS =","; OFS= ","} the main problem is how do i take the output fields and put them in a new order

Comment: You can create additional indexed arrays for the firstname and lastname (or, more elegantly perhaps, a single additional indexed array containing the string concatenation `$2","$3` indexed on `$1`)

Comment: so i can make an array for each index then put them on the new file on the print

Comment: so would that be something like say ``` total[$1]+=$6; name[$1]="$2","$3"

Comment: Close - `name[$1]=$2","$3` (`","` is a string literal while `$2` and `$3` are fields that shouldn't be quoted)

Comment: ... or keep it simple and just use `firstname[$1]=$2; lastname[$1]=$3`

Comment: ok and the print would look like print lname[i],",",fname[i],","lname[i],",",id[i],",",total[i]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '
  BEGIN {OFS=FS=","} 
  NR==1 {print "firstname","lastname","chargetotal","customerID"} 
  FNR>1 {fname[$1]=$2; lname[$1]=$3; chargetotal[$1]+=$4} 
  END {for(i in chargetotal) print fname[i],lname[i],chargetotal[i],i}
' file.csv
firstname,lastname,chargetotal,customerID
jeny,vel,38.39,4a7f057
Romo,goodrick,76.89,5efc522
```

Alternatively, with [Miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html)

```
$ mlr --csvlite --ofmt '%.2lf' stats1 -a sum -f charge -g customerID,firstname,lastname \
    then reorder -e -f customerID then rename charge_sum,chargetotal file.csv
firstname,lastname,chargetotal,customerID
Romo,goodrick,76.89,5efc522
jeny,vel,38.39,4a7f057
```